# Error when using mix function in LESS in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, less, parse-error, less-rails

Using the less-rails gem.

Using the following code to mix two colours:

```
@base: #ffdc52;
@add: #195742;
.colour{
    color: mix(@base, @add);
}
```

getting the following error:

```
Less::ParseError: error evaluating function `mix`: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mix`](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/functions.js#L107) needs three parameters:

```
mix: function (color1, color2, weight) {
    var p = weight.value / 100.0;
    ...
},
```

Comment: annoyingly, the less website states you only have to pass in the two color parameters